# How to display object's List property in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm currently having a problem in displaying some stuff in `ListView`. I have a normal C# `Student` class and a `Classroom` class. In `Classroom` class contains a List of `Student` classes which is shown below:

```
public class Classroom
{
    int classroomid {set;get;}
    List<Students> students{set;get;}
}
```

My question is if I bind my `DataSource` of the `ListView` to a List of objects of `Classroom`, how do I render the `Student` lists in the `ListView`?

```
<ListView>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("classroomid") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("students") %>'</asp:Label>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("students.name") %>'</asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code above essentially explains that what I'm trying to achieve, or possibly displays the student's details such as name or etc. Is there any way to achieve that? I do understand that nested `ListView` works, but I'm not sure how is the implementation.
Thank you for your help in advance. :-)

Comment: why you use label ? The label is for associate it with some other control and by clicking the label you give the focus to the associated control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.Join`:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblStudents"
    Text='<%# string.Join(",", (List<string>)Eval("students")) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

**Edit**: I missed that `Student` is a custom type. So you should better do this in the ListView's [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event for readability.

But it should work also on aspx:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblStudents"
    Text='<%# string.Join(",", ((List<Student>)Eval("students")).Select(s=>s.Name)) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

in codebehind:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label LblStudents = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblStudents");

        Classroom cr = e.Item.DataItem as Classroom;
        if (cr != null && cr.students != null && cr.students.Count > 0)   
        {
            LblStudents.Text = string.Join(",", cr.students.Select(s => s.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i can't seem to make it work.  Classroom class does not contain a property with the name 'students'. Any ideas?

Comment: @danial: Make it protected or public.

Comment: hi tim, it works when the List is string typed, but when i changed it to Student typed list, it fails.

Comment: @danial: Oh i missed somewhere that you're using a custom type. So what do you want as output, has `Student` overridden `ToString`?